# Laravel 5.2 multilanguage with dimsav/laravel-translatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using dimsav for multilanguage and I have this problem after doing step by step from the guid. ([dimsav](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable))

I have a Model Category:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;
class Category extends Model {
        use Translatable;
        public $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
 }
```

A CategoryTranslation:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class CategoryTranslation extends Model {
         public $timestamps = false;
}
```

And in Controller when I try to save this with a specific language I get an error. This is my controller:

```
$language = App::getLocale();
$user = Auth::user();
$category = new Category();
$category->translate('en')->name = Input::get('name');  //line 35
$category->save())
```

And error:

> at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Creating default object from
>   empty value',
>   'C:\workspace\applications\wamp\www\lutz-paletten\app\Http\Controllers\CategoryController.php',
>   '35', array('language' => 'en', 'user' => object(User), 'category' =>
>   object(Category))) in CategoryController.php line 35

PS: this is my migration:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('categoryId');
   $table->integer('user_id');
   $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('locale')->index();

    $table->unique(['category_id','locale']);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

What am I missing ? 
If I use this, it works:

```
$category->name = Input::get('name');
```

And it will be saved with what is set as AppLocale but how can I use it with `translate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this or not, but i think you should check with a couple of things:

**1-** delete the Parentheses when initiating the Category object so it will become:
`$category = new Category;`

**2-** Change the extra Parentheses after the save function so it will be:
`$category->save();`

**3-** make sure your input is named correctly.

and that's all i can see, hope you solved already :).

BTW you don't need that
`$table->integer('categoryId');` in your migration is not nessary since `$table->increments('id);` is playing that role!

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new record of Category, this last one saves record with your current Locale (default : en).

You just need to change `$category->translate('en')` by `$category->getNewTranslation('en')` or `$category->translateOrNew('en')` and it works !

For your example:

**Create a category with default locale (config/app.php ==> locale => 'en'):**

```
// CategoryController
public function createCategory(Request $request)
{
    // Save record in *categories* table 
    // And save the default language (config/app.php ==> locale) in *category_translations* table.
    $category = new Category::create($request);
}
```

**Create a translation in an existing category:**

```
public function createCategoryTranslation(Request $request, $id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id)

    // Solution 1 : If you want to explain the fields to be saved.
    $category->getNewTranslation('en')->name = $request->input('name');

    // Solution 2 : Mass assignement if you have multiple fields to be saved.
    $category->getNewTranslation('en')->fill($request);

    $category->save()
}
```

**Update a translation:**

```
public function updateCategoryTranslation(Request $request, $id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id)

    // Solution 1 : If you want to explain the fields to be saved.
    $category->translate('en')->name = $request->input('name');

    // Solution 2 : Mass assignement if you have multiple fields to be saved.
    $category->translate('en')->fill($request);

    $category->save()
}
```

**CreateOrUpdate translation:**

```
public function createOrUpdateCategoryTranslation(Request $request, $id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id)

    // Solution 1 : If you want to explain the fields to be saved.
    $category->translateOrNew('en')->name = $request->input('name');

    // Solution 2 : Mass assignement if you have multiple fields to be saved.
    $category->translateOrNew('en')->fill($request);

    $category->save()
}
```